# Create instance of implementation of generic class based on type of Class<T>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following class layout:

```cs
abstract class GenericClass<TArgs> where TArgs : ArgsBaseClass { }
abstract class ArgsBaseClass { }

class RandomArgs : ArgsBaseClass { }
class RandomClass : GenericClass<RandomArgs> { }
```

Now I want to be able to create an instance of `RandomClass` from an instance of `RandomArgs`, without knowing that it should be `RandomClass`. I.e. somehow I need to derive the fact that `RandomClass` implements `GenericClass<RandomArgs>`.

I'm able to create an instance of `GenericClass<RandomArgs>` using:

```cs
void CreateSpecificInstance(ArgsBaseClass args)
{
    Type genericType = typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(args));
    var genericInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType, typeof(args));
    // But then I need help for the following step:
    Type specificType = ...  // in this case RandomClass, but should be derived from 'args'.
    var specificInstance = (specificType)genericInstance;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**

Basically I have multiple `args` classes. Each `args` class has a respective 'normal' class that can be initialised with this `args` class. Hence `GenericClass<ArgsBaseClass>`.

Now I want to be able to create an instance of the 'normal' class whenever I pass an instance of the `ArgsBaseClass` to some function (in my example named `CreateSpecificInstance`.

As per my comments, I guess it would be possible to create a mapping between each `args` class and 'normal' class e.g. using a dictionary, but whenever you add a new `args` + 'normal' class combination you also need to update this dictionary. Hence I guess a solution using reflection should be used here, however I don't see a solution using reflection that doesn't iterate over all classes in the assembly or namespace, hence I'm asking for help.

Comment: You should explain why you need this for instead.

Comment: You would have to search all loaded assemblies for such a type. What if there were multiple such types, what would you do then?

Comment: Also it's unclear which types you know at compile time. Do you know the exact type of `args`, can you make that generic `TArgs args) where TArgs : ArgsBaseClass`?

Comment: Please take a look at xyproblem.info. As @aybe commented, please explain what are you trying to achieve, instead of only asking about the problem you have with what you're trying.

Comment: @aybe @Pablo Recalde  Basically I need a `var x = new RandomClass()`, but I only know that I have an instance of `RandomArgs` and that `RandomClass : GenericClass<RandomArgs>`. The solution must work for different implementations of both abstract classes though, say I have a `RandomClass2 : GenericClass<RandomArgs2>`, etc. In theory I could make a dictionary with `{ RandomArgs: RandomClass, RandomArgs2: RandomClass2}` etc. But whenever I add a new Argsclass a need a new entry in the dict, so I guess I'll need reflection.

Comment: However it is enforced that there is only one class per args class I.e. There is `RandomClass : GenericClass<RandomArgs>` but no `RandomClass2 : GenericClass<RandomArgs>` or `RandomClass : GenericClass<RandomArgs2>`

Comment: Again, you're telling that you absolutely need solution X though it doesn't make any sense. Edit your question and explain in litteral terms what design you are looking for, not how to achieve X technically.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding things, you can't do that. What if some other class implements `GenericClass<RandomArgs>`. The best you could do would be to test every class in the assembly you think it's in to test if your generic class is assignable from your random class. Try renaming your classes to things that have meaning. For example `class HouseCat : Animal<Feline>`. But, say there's also a `class Tiger : Animal<Feline>`

Comment: @aybe I updated my question, hope this helps.

Comment: Guys, the requirement DOES make sense. I suspect that if he asked that he needs a "dynamic way of registering generic implementation classes" the question would be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing to answer this question is a lot of really specific details, particular to your implementation.

So, this answer is not a specific solution, but aims to describe a set of solutions, or at least ingredients for the solution.

The most difficult thing you can encounter in this kind of problems is dynamic discovery of interfaces and types. E.g. you don't know at compile time the full list of `Args` types and `GenericClass` implementations.

If you know it beforehand, you're lucky. Just load a `Dictionary<Type, Type>` with the `Args` type as a key and the implementation type as value.

If you don't, you have an extra problem to solve: how to uniquely identify the implementation types? There are many way to solve this problem, too, but they involve some form of `Assembly.GetTypes()` or (better yet) using a good IoC framework (i like [Autofac](https://autofac.org/) the most) with built in assembly scanning capabilities. You would need to solve also the problem (maybe just in principle, but it's a question you need an answer for) of what happens if you find two implementations for the same args.

Back to our implementation type. We have an `Args` instance or type, we have our dictionary of types, so we find the `Type` of the correct implementation of `GenericClass<TArgs>`. Now you need a way to build instances. If you can ensure you have a parameterless constructor, you can just call `Activator.CreateInstance(myGenericType)`. This will give you an instance of `RandomClass`, boxed inside an `object`.

You will need to cast it in some way, in order to use it, maybe to `GenericClass<RandomArgs>`.

If you do not have a parameterless constructor, and you can, try using an IoC container to make the hard work of discovering the constructor depencencies for you. Again, `Autofac` is a nice candidate, but there are a lot of alternatives and this is a deep rabbit hole.

So, in easiest case, you just need something like this:

```cs
private Dictionary<Type, Type> _implementations =
    new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

public void RegisterImplementation<TArgs, TImpl>()
    where TArgs : ArgsBaseClass
    where TImpl : GenericClass<TArgs>, new()
{
    _implementations[typeof(TArgs)] = typeof(TImpl);
}

public GenericClass<TArgs> MakeClass<TArgs>(TArgs args) where TArgs : ArgsBaseClass
{
    var implementationType = _implementations.TryGetValue(typeof(TArgs), out var t)
        ? t
        : throw new ArgumentException("The args type " + typeof(TArgs) + " is unrecognized.", nameof(args));

    return (GenericClass<TArgs>)Activator.CreateInstance(implementationType);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer, I think however that I will go a separate route for now and put that as an answer as wel.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go another route and use the [Factory Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) instead.